# JDialog allow user to only change width of the dialog

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

Does anyone know if it is possible to limit how the user resizes a JDialog?

I know i can call the method setResizible(boolean) and that disables or enables the user from resizing the JDialog, but is there a way to restrict the user from changing the height of the window but allowing him to change the width?

The dialog I'm creating looks funny if it grows vertically but horizontally growing the component could be a benefit to the user.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What if my fonts have different metrics? What layout are you using?

Comment: simply don't even think of it - nothing worse than a not resizable dialog with it's buttons below the visible area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a `ComponentListener` to the JDialog, and check in `componentResized` if height changed. This could be implemented by extending the JDialog class this way:

```
public class Dialog extends javax.swing.JDialog {

    public Dialog(java.awt.Frame parent, boolean modal) {
        super(parent, modal);
        initComponents();
        final int h = getHeight();
        addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
                Rectangle b = getBounds();
                if (b.height != h) {
                    b.height = h;
                    setBounds(b);
                }
                super.componentResized(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this trick works, but the result looks ugly. There are visible repaint artefacts.